# Need some advice with create html form?

Tags: html, forms, select

Is it correct to make such an element through the select tag? I doubt because then need to set too many values in option, but the select tag is the most comfortable for mobile devices.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How about a really big [`<input type=date>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)?

> `<input>` elements of type date create input fields allowing a date to be easily entered — this includes year, month and day, but not time.
>
> The control's UI varies in general from browser to browser; at the moment support is patchy, see Browser compatibility for further details. In unsupported browsers, the control degrades gracefully to a simple `<input type="text">`.

[Can I Use: Date and time input types?](http://caniuse.com/input-datetime/embed/)

```css
input[type=date] {
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<input type=date value="2017-07-29">
```

### Alternatively; using [`<input type=number>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

If UI is at least as important as UX, you could use three `<input type=number>` elements with appropriately [set `min` and `max` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#Specifying_minimum_and_maximum_values).

> You can use the [`min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-min) and [`max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-max) attributes to specify a minimum and maximum value that the field can have.

Although this doesn't provide the default handling of `<input type=date>`, and validation will need to be carried out by JavaScript, it does provide good accesibility and at least [validation that the input values are numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#Validation), which can be used easily to create a [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```css
form {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #1f373e;
  color: #aaa;
}
fieldset {
  border: 0;
}
fieldset:before {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre-line;
  content: "Date\A";
}
input {
  width: 3ch;
  margin: 1.5em 0 .5em;
  padding: .4em 0 .4em .4em;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: .2em;
}
input:first-child {
  width: 5ch;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="number" placeholder="YYYY" name="year" min="1900" max="2100"> &ndash;
    <input type="number" placeholder="MM" name="month" min="1" max="12"> &ndash;
    <input type="number" placeholder="DD" name="day"min="1" max="31">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: <input type=date> it's nice variant, but I can't imagine, how to stylize it for my task?

Comment: Personally, if comfort for users is important (as it should be) I would always opt for the most simple, default interface possible. Using built in components provides the best performance, accessibility, reliability and familiarity. If style causes or requires degradation of user experience, it's worse than lipstick on a pig. This `<input>` is specifically designed to handle dates in all their complexity, and I don't envy anyone trying to build something better from scratch. You might find some decent libraries to do it though - with all the overheads they incur.

Comment: @NikolayCk - I added another example using `<input type=number>`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a possible usecase for the select tag. As you can see in 
[this link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select), you can set the option values like   `<option value="1989">1989</option>` and so on for dates.